# Class not found in fileName.php

Tags: php

I downloaded the example from here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f

This has been officially provided by the Microsoft community. I downloaded this example and changed

At the top of file ReportRequests.php

The path :

```
include 'bingads\ReportingClasses.php';
include 'bingads\ClientProxy.php';
```

was switched to

```
include 'bingads/ReportingClasses.php';
include 'bingads/ClientProxy.php';
```

since I am not on windows but linux.

Also, there is

```
use BingAds\Reporting\KeywordPerformanceReportRequest;
```

but yet I keep getting

```
Class 'BingAds\Reporting\KeywordPerformanceReportRequest' not found in fileName.php
```

on line

```
 $report = new KeywordPerformanceReportRequest();
```

Why is it and how do I fix it?

Comment: Silly question but... Those files definitely do exist in that location... Right?

Comment: can you please check once.Is there file that you are calling?

Comment: I think you are working with Bing Ads API in PHP.right?

Comment: @Reisclef: Yes, they do. Otherwise it will give file not found which it did when I had not changed it to backward slashes used for paths in linux

Comment: @VasimVanzara: Yes, I am working with Bing ads API and the files are there other it would not no file in the location error which it did before I changed forward slashes to backward for path in linux

Comment: Where did you get 
use BingAds\Reporting\KeywordPerformanceReportRequest; ?
Shouldn't it be
use BingAds\V9\Reporting\KeywordPerformanceReportRequest?

Comment: You have to download a package before it

Comment: Oh Thanks. Which one? @VasimVanzara

Comment: @JakubJudas: Hey, Thanks. That worked. How did you know it needed to be switched to that?

Comment: @JakubJudas: You can post that as an answer. I would be happy to accept it :)

Comment: I posted it including explanation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The namespace used in ReportingClasses.php is BingAds\V9\Reporting.

So the use statement should say

```
use BingAds\V9\Reporting\KeywordPerformanceReportRequest
```

Comment: I wouldn't have guessed. So awesome! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to download a package before use an API you can find here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/Bing-Ads-API-Version-9-in-fb27761f

I think you are missing this two lines at starting  of code:

```
include 'bingads\ReportingClasses.php';
include 'bingads\ClientProxy.php';
```

Example code :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bing-ads-php-code-examples.aspx

Comment: Hey, I mentioned in in my question itself that I have these lines at top of my file